# Aligning vertically centered and horizontally left text of cells in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

My minimum working example :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{.18\textwidth} m{.18\textwidth} m{.18\textwidth} m{.18\textwidth} m{.18\textwidth}} 
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 1 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 2 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 3 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 4 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 5  \\
\hline Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 1 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 2 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 3 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 4 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I am trying to align my table

1. **Centered vertically**  (this point seems ok)
2. **Left horizontally**

However, given my above code the text is **not** aligned on left horizontally, but justified, which gives some horrible display with tons of word breaks. I simply want to force it aligned to left.

[image: Issue]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a raggedright column type but didn't use it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }m{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{.18\textwidth} L{.18\textwidth} L{.18\textwidth} L{.18\textwidth} L{.18\textwidth}} 
\hline \rowcolor{lightgray} Lipsum Lipsum 1 & x x x x x x x xLipsum Lipsum Lipsum 2 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum 3 & y y y y y y y y y  x x x x x x xLipsum Lipsum Lipsum 4 & Lipsum 5  \\
\hline Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 1 & Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 2 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 3 & Lipsum Lipsum Lipsum UNDER 4 & Lipsum Lipsum g g g g gg g g Lipsum UNDER 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes but now it's not centered vertically, even if the align on left is working now.

Comment: @Hosare The vertical positioning is `m` as in your example, it is hard to see in the example as all entries are the same height

Comment: I used other texts that I had to remove because of private data. If you modify it, you will notice the alignment down vertically.

Comment: The idea of a minimal _example_ is that it shows the problem, it's the OP's job to provide the example:-) I'll change the text and post an image

Comment: @Hosare text changed so it shows vertical centering (the code is as before)

Comment: Sorry if I thought that it would help providing some code. Thanks for the advice, next time I will only ask for what I am looking for.

Comment: @Hosare it wasn't a _bad_ MWE (a lot better than most:-) just would have been better to have long and short texts to show vertical positioning. Anyway is the image what you need? (If not, I didn't understand the question)